# Django, Querysets. How to perform search on 400mb sql query set faster?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I Have a problem. I'm working with a 400mb postgres database. I have to perform searches with a lot of different filters. It takes me around a minute to load the page.

example from views.py, the task is to search all the possible combinations of word's letters. Like cat > act > atc etc. :

```
def neighb():
    count = 0
    words = []
    mylist = re.findall(r'\w', word)
    combinations = (list(itertools.permutations(mylist)))
    result = ''
    for comb in combinations:
        for letters in comb:
            result += letters
        if data.filter(form_v=result).exists():
            count += 1
            words.append(result)
        result = ''
    return count, words
```

So, is there some way to make it faster?

Comment: One solution I can think of is using `Q` and doing an `or` join on all possibilities. e.g. `data.filter(Q(form_v='cat') | Q(form_v='act') | ...)`. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Comment: Can you give more insights on what sort of a task you are solving, I feel you might be better off by converting the data or changing your search approach. For example you can add another field to your table which would contain `form_v` value with all letters sorted alphabetically, then you don't have to search for all permutations, only for the sorted letters value  (`act` instead of `cat`).

Comment: Note that 400mb isn't really very big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There few things you are not doing optimally.

**First:** don't join strings like this

```
for letters in comb:
   result += letters
```

do this

```
result = ''.join(comb)
```

**Second:** you should always try to do as less db queries as possible. In your case you will do it for every combination. Why not just get filter by all combinations and then get all words that actually in db. This way you will do only one db query.

```
def neighb(data, word):
    mylist = re.findall(r'\w', word)
    combinations = [''.join(c) for c in itertools.permutations(mylist)]
    words = list(data.filter(form_v__in=combinations).values_list('form_v', flat=True))
    return len(words), words
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You helped me very much! Thanks. Vladislav.